# request.form.get("xxxxx") returns None

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests

Ive been looking for quite a while now but i simply cant get this working i started working with flask and html two days ago but it keeps returning none

Heres the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"></form>
            
            <label>Chose your numbers</label> <br>
            
            <label> Number 1</label>
            <p><input name="location" type="text" /></p>
            
            <label> Number 2</label>
            <p><input name="location2" type="text" /></p>
            

            <label>The result is</label>
            <label>{{result}}</label><br>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

And heres the python  code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
import ops

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods= ["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        o = request.form.get('op')
        if o == "+":
            return redirect(url_for("sum"))
            
                   

@app.route("/sum", methods= ["GET", "POST"])
def sum():
    s1 = request.args.get('location')
    s2 = request.args.get('location2')
    return render_template("sum.html", result= ops.adding(float(s1) + float(s2)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

My problem is that location 1 and 2 are simpli not getting passed from html to pythom some how
Heres a picture as this is my first post and i dont realy know how this site works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAuUS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your form tag too soon (`</form>`), also you are trying to do `POST` request and trying to access the values using GET parameters on Python code.

Fixed HTML, which sends the form values as GET parameters e.g. `/sum?location=x&location2=y`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="GET" action="{{ url_for('sum') }}">
            
            <label>Chose your numbers</label> <br>
            
            <label> Number 1</label>
            <p><input name="location" type="text" /></p>
            
            <label> Number 2</label>
            <p><input name="location2" type="text" /></p>
            

            <label>The result is</label>
            <label>{{result}}</label><br>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

`/sum` route:

```py
@app.route("/sum")
def sum():
    s1 = request.args.get('location')
    s2 = request.args.get('location2')
    if s1 and s2:
        return render_template("sum.html", result= ops.adding(float(s1) + float(s2)))
    return render_template("sum.html")
```

`request.args` docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args

Comment: I cannot thank u enough but what what is teh point on "   if s1 and s2:  "

Comment: Simple check that makes sure that the value of `s1` and `s2` is not `None`, there is no point in trying to add the values together is one of them is `None`.